# Setting a server for JWebunit Tests

Tags: java, junit, jetty, jwebunit

I'm using [JwebUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/) to test my JSP pages in a web application.
Since JWebUnit requires a base urlto work. JwebUnit has `setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8080/MyWebapp");` to set the base url which is used `@Before`of Junit Test. I need to start a server and deploy the webapp there before each test and stop the server after that. Can anyone please suggest me a simple way to do this with `Jetty` or other options...

Comment: Please post an example junit showing your initialization of jetty + jwebunit, then point out where you need this information.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [Server Rule](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/server-rule/). It provides a JUnit rule that starts and stops a Jetty web server.